# onkeyup doesn't work with ids with numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I encountered a problem where onkeyup doesn't work in ids with numbers. For example, id="lname1".

This code works:

```
<html>
<body>
 Enter your firstname: <input type="text" id="fname" 
 onkeyup="myFunction('fname')">
 <br/>Enter your lastname: <input type="text" id="lname" 
 onkeyup="myFunction('lname')">
 <p>My name is: <span id="demo"></span></p>

 <script>
 function myFunction(ele) {
     var x = document.getElementById(ele).value;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

However, when I change the id to fname1 or lname1, onkeyup doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
 Enter your firstname: <input type="text" id="fname" 
 onkeyup="myFunction('fname1')">
 <br/>Enter your lastname: <input type="text" id="lname" 
 onkeyup="myFunction('lname1')">
 <p>My name is: <span id="demo"></span></p>

 <script>
 function myFunction(ele) {
     var x = document.getElementById(ele).value;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This example doesn't work. Why?
By the way, the reason why the ids have numbers is because I dynamically create them. Can anyone please explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because you are passing in `fname1` but there are no elements with that ID, so `x` will not point to any element.

Comment: Yes, I edited it. but it still didn't work

Comment: @Rouge - With respect, with the edit, it *does* work: http://jsbin.com/topatuxusu/edit?html,output

Comment: It does... (kind of?) https://jsfiddle.net/c7enjuow/ Note that you are overwriting the inner HTML of the same element though, so last name will overwrite the first name.

Comment: Tried it in Tryit Editor, but didn't work,

Comment: Since the edit invalidates existing answers, I'm reverting it.

Comment: @Rouge - If changing the IDs so they match doesn't work in some TryIt thing you're using, then the TryIt thing you're using is broken.

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

Because you've changed the ID that it's looking for (for instance, from `fname` to `fname1`), but you *haven't* changed the `id` attribute of the element (you still have `id="fname"`).

There's no need for `id`s here at all, simply pass `this` into your handler and remove the call to `getElementById`:

```
<html>
<body>
Enter your firstname: <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
<br/>Enter your lastname: <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
<p>My name is: <span id="demo"></span></p>

<script>
function myFunction(ele) {
    var x = ele.value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Live copy:

```js
function myFunction(ele) {
    var x = ele.value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
Enter your firstname: <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
<br/>Enter your lastname: <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
<p>My name is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

As Terry points out in a comment, you probably wanted to target *different* output elements, since typing in either input will put *just* that input's value in the `demo` element. Perhaps pass the ID of the target element as an argument and have more than one:

```js
function myFunction(ele, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ele.value;
}
```

```html
Enter your firstname: <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this, 'fnameOutput')">
<br/>Enter your lastname: <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this, 'lnameOutput')">
<p>
  My name is:
  <span id="fnameOutput"></span>
  <span id="lnameOutput"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: OP might not realise this, but his code will still somehow not work as expected, since both elements are writing to the same element. So instead of having first + last name displayed, they will instead overwrite each other.

Comment: @Terry - That's true. It's sort of the *next* problem. :-)

Comment: True that, just wait for it... ;)

Comment: @Terry - Added something to mention it. :-)

Comment: SO should allow people to vote +5 for abstractions ;) awesome!

Comment: Yes, I know that it replaces the previous thing I type, my concern is that there is nothing really that is printed :)

Comment: @Rouge - The above clearly *does* show things when you type in the inputs. (As does your code [if you add the `1` to the ends of the IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434557/onkeyup-doesnt-work-with-ids-with-numbers/50434595?noredirect=1#comment87883248_50434557).)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass name at all. Simply pass `this`. To retain the previous name you have to use `+=` instead of `=`:

```js
function myFunction(ele) {
   var x = ele.value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x;
}
```

```html
Enter your firstname: <input type="text" id="fname" 
onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
<br/>Enter your lastname: <input type="text" id="lname" 
onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
<p>My name is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```